# Make datatables load faster with more than 10.000 data

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am new to datatables and I am making a website search data using datatables. But mysql data is more than 10,000. When I try to search data on my web, datatables are very long displaying data. Can anyone help me, how do I get datatables to display tables faster with large data. Thank you

PHP:

```
    <?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$columns = array('id', 'datetime', 'temperature', 'humidity');


$query = "SELECT id, datetime, temperature, humidity FROM data WHERE ";

if($_POST["is_date_search"] == "yes")
{
 $query .= 'DATE(datetime) BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND  "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" AND ';
}

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
  (id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%")
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= "GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%d-%M-%Y-%H:%i:%s') ORDER BY 'id'";
}




$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query );

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = ""; 
 $sub_array[] = $row["datetime"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["temperature"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["humidity"];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM data";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
      todayBtn:'linked',
      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      autoclose: true
     });

     fetch_data('no');

     function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
     {
      var dataTable = $('#tabel_data').DataTable({
          "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
       "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                 {
                    extend: 'print',

                     filename: 'datatable'

                },

            ],

       "paging": false,
       "processing" : true,
       "serverSide" : true,
       bFilter:false,
       "ajax" : {
        url:"fetch.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
         is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
        }, 
       }
      });
         dataTable.on('draw.dt', function () {
    var info = dataTable.page.info();
    dataTable.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied', page: 'applied', }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + info.start;
        dataTable.cell(cell).invalidate('dom'); 
    });
}); 


 }


     $('#search').click(function(){
      var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
      var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
      if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
      {
       $('#tabel_data').DataTable().destroy();
       fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
        document.getElementById('tabel').style.display = "block";  
      }
      else
      {
       alert("Date Required");
      }
     }); 



    });
```

Comment: This is simply due to weight of data. You should implement paging and/or filtering on the server side to reduce the number of records which need to be sent to the client and displayed.

Comment: ... and probably you have set wrong indexes... what is `EXPLAIN` telling you?

Comment: Have you make your id a primary key, and (as long as you don't have too many field to query) index query field (date_time). Also please look at sql injection and fix your code :)
Also, you don't need to count results for `SELECT *`, just use `SELECT COUNT(id)` which returns the number of rows

Comment: in addition to the other comments, 10,000 is very small

Comment: For a MySQL database, perhaps, but the DOM will most likely struggle with that amount of data depending on how it's displayed.

Comment: off topic, but: your code is vulnerable to SQL injections because you do not sanitize your input data and pass it directly to the database.

Answer (score 1):

1) use pagination  [how to use pagination with PHP and mysql](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm) instead of a simple query like below.

```
"SELECT * FROM data";
```

2) Dot `select *` because * will select unnecessary fields also instead define column name for which you want to show data

example:

```
select name,page,amt from data
```

your final query will look like

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary FROM employee LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit;
```

check the link above how to use pagination with PHP and mysql